# Enabling and disabling network card through commandline

Tags: command-line, networking

Can anybody help me to how can I enable and disable network card through terminal?

Comment: if you want to disable for example the `eth0` (ethernet port), you can `sudo ifconfig eth0 down` which will disable (down) the port.  changing down to up will re-enable it.  use `ifconfig` to view your ports.  this works on a port basis; so a nic (network interface card) with four ports will require each port to be disabled individually.

Comment: @chrisguiver That sounds like an answer. Would you be willing to post it (or something like it) as one?

Answer (score 40):

Since `ifconfig` has been [deprecated](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2009/03/msg00780.html) for many years now, you should probably use the `ip` command :

To list the interfaces:

```
ip link
```

or with the ip addresses:

```
ip a
```

To take one down:

```
if=eth0
sudo ip link set $if down
```

Comment: or for enabling use  `sudo ip link set eth0 up`

Comment: How does one keep it down after reboot?

Answer (score 18):

use `ifconfig` to view your ethernet or NIC ports (to get port names; eg. eth0 was the first port on my machine, next was eth1 etc)

to disable say port named eth0 use

`sudo ifconfig eth0 down`

to re-enable the port use

`sudo ifconfig eth0 up`

note:  this disables (down) and enables (up) each port individually.  if for example a NIC (network interface card) has four ports on a card, you need to enable/disable each port individually.

Comment: Is this permanent?

Comment: It pulls the interface down/up as the machine is running, but on reboot, or a restart of networking [service] the NIC status will return to default.

Comment: What do you mean by "port"? I don't see any port number specified in your commands.

Comment: The *port* used in that example was eth0, for my current workstation there is no eth0, but it would be enp0s25 (I'm using a later kernel which uses a different naming technique)

Comment: There must be another command to toggle the wifi card with fn+f8 - network symbol on my laptop. This is also possible from cmd. The cmd is something with list.

Answer (score 10):

To see list of network cards:

```
lshw -C network
```

You will see all the network cards. Attention to **logical name** example:

```
logical name: wlp6s0
logical name: enp7s0
```

So just use `ifconfig` to enable or disable it.

Examples:

- **Enable** `sudo ifconfig wlp6s0 up`
- **Disable**: `sudo ifconfig enp7s0 down`

Comment: I don't see any logical name while running "lshw -C network". Do we have way to find location name?

Comment: does not do anything on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

This can be also achieved by using Network-Manager :

- **nmcli con show** (lists all the available interfaces, can add the --active option for displaying only the active ones)
- **nmcli dev disconnect** *enp0s3* (for disconnecting enp0s3 for example)
- **nmcli con up** *enp0s3*(for bringing it back up)