Ubuntu 22 and 24 LTS won't suspend, except in unusual circumstances
I'm having a weird problem where Ubuntu won't suspend, except in unusual circumstances.
By "won't suspend", I mean that selecting Suspend from the top-right power menu will cause the screen to briefly go black, followed immediately by the unsuspended/woken-up login screen.
This is a Dell Precision 3590 that originally shipped with Ubuntu 22 LTS from the factory at the end of October 2024. Dell provides a factory image/recovery image for this model here.
Everything below reproduces 100% of the time.

Wiping the machine and installing the factory image causes suspend to always work.
Afterward, going to Software Updater and downloading all updates causes suspend to stop working.
If I download only the security updates, suspend also stops working.
Wiping the machine and installing Ubuntu 22 LTS (from the official website) causes suspend to never work.
A clean install of Ubuntu 24 LTS also causes suspend to never work.
A clean install of Ubuntu 24.10 (non-LTS) also causes suspend to never work.
Starting from Ubuntu 24 LTS, the kernel is on 6.8.0. If I manually upgrade to any mainline kernel including 6.11, suspend never works.
If I manually downgrade to mainline kernel 6.7.10 (the latest version of 6.7), suspend always works.
If I manually downgrade to mainline kernel 6.6.51 (the latest version of 6.6), suspend works but the brightness buttons on the laptop stop working. The same applies to lower versions of 6.x.
Ubuntu will not boot past GRUB if I attempt to downgrade to the latest version of 5.x.

I am not sure what to make of this, especially since mainline kernel 6.7.x is supposed to be unsupported by now. I do not know where to start debugging this either. Ideally suspend should work on a stable kernel version, without needing a super-exact intermediate kernel version. Any help would be gladly appreciated.
Edit: Output of journalctl over the last 5 minutes immediately after a failed suspend, with the -k and -p tags:
Nov 22 00:49:09 zowayix-Precision-3590 kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: PM: pci_pm_suspend(): e1000e_pm_suspend+0x0/0xa0 [e1000e] returns -2
Nov 22 00:49:09 zowayix-Precision-3590 kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: PM: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x1b0 returns -2
Nov 22 00:49:09 zowayix-Precision-3590 kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: PM: failed to suspend async: error -2
Nov 22 00:49:09 zowayix-Precision-3590 kernel: PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
Nov 22 00:49:10 zowayix-Precision-3590 kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: PM: pci_pm_suspend(): e1000e_pm_suspend+0x0/0xa0 [e1000e] returns -2
Nov 22 00:49:10 zowayix-Precision-3590 kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: PM: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x1b0 returns -2
Nov 22 00:49:10 zowayix-Precision-3590 kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: PM: failed to suspend async: error -2
Nov 22 00:49:10 zowayix-Precision-3590 kernel: PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
Nov 22 00:49:12 zowayix-Precision-3590 kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: Hardware Error
Nov 22 00:49:15 zowayix-Precision-3590 kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: Hardware Error
Nov 22 00:49:18 zowayix-Precision-3590 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
Nov 22 00:49:18 zowayix-Precision-3590 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x0027B0C0 for RT uCode

lshw output is too large to fit here, so I dumped it into pastebin: https://pastebin.com/Yq3JfhrB

Welcome to Ask. My experience of uncooprative suspend is that there are several things that can cause it and you have to investigate it through the logs. One of the most common I have is is the 'Canary is Staving' https://askubuntu.com/questions/86974/what-is-the-canary-thread-and-why-is-it-starving which, itself can be caused by other faults. As a starting point append to your question the output of 'lshw' and a journal report over the time of an attempted 'suspend' journalctl --since "2024-11-22 00:20" --until "2024-11-22 00:30" (with '-k' then '-p emerg..err' to help encapsulate things)

Thanks, I've added the output of the above 2 commands on kernel 6.8.x. I'll also separately take a look at what those -2 error codes mean. I don't understand what "Hardware Error" means though, since the hardware seems to work fine on a different kernel version.

Self-resolved using a workaround; thanks to @david for pointing me in the right direction. I searched for pci_pm_suspend "-2" and found the following similar bug report from June 2024: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=218936
While the details aren't exactly the same, I did test some stuff that the above reporter mentioned, including that suspend suddenly works again with an Ethernet cable connected (and breaks again if you unplug the cable and suspend again).
The full workaround (based on the above reporter's workaround) I used was:

Run sudo rmmod e1000e to disable ethernet.

If you're okay with manually doing this once on every boot, you can stop here.
If you need ethernet, run sudo modprobe e1000e to turn it back on. This re-breaks suspend, but that's okay because plugging in the Ethernet cable makes the bug go away anyway. Then when you later unplug the Ethernet cable, you'll have to rerun sudo rmmod e1000e to re-disable ethernet and get suspend working again.


I used the following ugly hack to autorun rmmod on boot:

sudo visudo, add myusernamefoo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/rmmod below the %sudo line.
crontab -e, add @reboot /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/rmmod e1000e.



(There's probably a nicer way to autorun rmmod, but the above was the fastest to add (and remove later if need be). If you know of a nicer and faster way, please let me know.)
Now I have stable Ubuntu kernel (not mainline kernel) 6.8.0, with suspend working in an acceptable manner.

I think there are more elegant ways to disable the network card. See the following link for details. https://askubuntu.com/questions/965343/enabling-and-disabling-network-card-through-commandline

I have the same issue. However downgrading to kernel 6.8.0-41 solved the issue for me. I am on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
